# Filtering In MATLAB using filter()

Tags: matlab

I am trying to filter a sinusoidal signal from random signal ( as a noise ) using

```
filter()
```

The problem is that the result is not filtered correctly , here is the code :

```
n=0:10:5000; 
x=sin(2*pi*0.002*n); 
subplot(3,2,1); 
stem(n,x); 
title('original signal')
noise=rand(size(n)); 
subplot(3,2,2);
stem(n,noise) ; 
title('random signal')
y=x+noise; 
subplot(3,2,3);
stem(n,y); 
title('noisy signal')
b=[1 1 1];
a=[1 1 1]; 
out=filter(b,a,y); 
subplot(3,2,4);
stem(n,out); 
title('filtered signal')
```

Comment: Define "not correct".

Comment: I mean that the filtered signal is not as the original one , it is still noisy .

Comment: That means you need to design a better filter...

Comment: I know but i was wondering if this problem is due to these filter coefficients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most fundamental problem is that your filter is doing nothing.  Your `out` variable is equal to your `y` variable.  Were you trying to design either a lowpass or bandpass filter?

Another problem is that your noise has nonzero mean, so it creates another tone with frequency 0 near your target tone.  Was this what you intended?